# get text of clicked a tag element with siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to get text on `<a>` element as shown in plunker, for the first click it shows text string correctly, but if i click again it shows twice and thrice next, not sure how to prevent it. any Help ??

Thanks in advance

http://plnkr.co/edit/efnFSDU1lkW8JvNzk4zz?p=preview

Comment: where is your code? what is plnkr.co/edit/efnFSDU1lkW8JvNzk4zz?p=preview
?

Comment: Controllers in angular are not meant to host DOM code.

Comment: in @mahi's defense, plnkr is one of the main angular code playground sites

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `Angular` you don't need use `jQuery` events, you can pass `$event` to your function and get text from current target, like so

```
$scope.getWord = function ($event) {
      alert(angular.element($event.target).text());
}

<a class="refer-word" ng-click="getWord($event)">javascript</a>
<a class="refer-word" ng-click="getWord($event)" name ="client">client</a>
```

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/0GG5tphsPurV2vgVD0LZ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

just use `.off()` in jquery

```
$(document).off('click').on("click", ".refer-word", function() {
                    var passedWord = $(this).text();
                    alert(passedWord);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are registering a new click event handler each time you are clicking on an element.

In my opinion the best solution would be to write your own directive:

```js
var app=angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  
}]);

app.directive('showTooltip', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.addClass('refer-word');
      element.bind('click', function(){
        alert(element.text());
      })
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.refer-word {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <div>
    <div> 
      <p>it is a <data-show-tooltip>javascript</data-show-tooltip> framework for <data-show-tooltip>client</data-show-tooltip> side</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @ boindiil Thanks for explaining using directives, I can keep this mind for other use case.

Answer (score 0):

your event binding location is actually wrong,
don't bind inside the action but bind inside the controller or any init place (only once)

the action could be triggered multiple times and it will rebind the event again and again .. that's why all the events will be called when the action is invoked in addition to binding another one too

try this for example

```
app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    //your event if you must have it this way
    $(document).on("click", ".refer-word", function() {
                    var passedWord = $(this).text();
                    //alert(passedWord);
                    console.log(passedWord);
            });
    $scope.getWord = function(){
        //action to be done
    }
}]);
```